# UITableView setEditing - Default buttons are too small on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, edit

I have an app that works on iPad/iPhone/iPod and I am setting variables for the table row height and font sizes based on screen size so everything scales in proportion.

When I setEditing on the UITableView to allow deletions, the default buttons on the left and right are tiny, is there a way to scale them to be in proportion to the table row height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved in later versions of iOS